# Paypal RecurringPayments: интеграция регулярных платежей на сайт

Tags: paypal

Добрый день. Есть непонятки с интеграцией регулярных платежей на сайт. Обычные разовые (`expressCheckout`) уже прикручены и исправно работают.

Ситуация следующая: Клиент оформляет услугу на сайте, со стоимостью ХХ USD, я его посылаю по известному маршруту: `SetExpressCheckout -> GetExpressCheckoutDetails -> CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`. После этого, у клиента создаётся подписка, которая оплачивается не сразу(в течении часа), к тому же при оформлении подписки на шлюзе `paypal` я не нашёл упоминания о сумме платежа, что меня смутило.

После последнего шага клиент возвращается на сайт и видит что оплата прошла успешно. Подписка активна... наверное.

Проблемы:
Как узнать, прошла ли оплата? как узнать, прошли ли оплата в следующем месяце? как узнать, не отказался ли клиент от подписки в своём профиле?

Уверен, что все эти "как узнать" делаются через IPN, но как конкретно их использовать мне непонятно, хотя бы примеры ответов посмотреть.

Может есть способ проще, допустим, после одноразовой оплаты сделать галку "Сделать платёж регулярным" и создать подписку, которая оплатится не сразу, а в следующем месяце.

Comment: Не помню как на пейпеле, но в основном отложенные платежи реализуются сервер-сервер - запросами. То есть, по факту оплаты процессинговый центр формирует внутренний запрос на ваш сервер, где передает данные об успешной оплате, а в первом запросе (когда вы перенаправили пользователя) вам приходит состояние -"ожидает оплаты", "отложенная оплата".

Comment: Это понятно, что "сервер-сервер". Хотелось бы услышать совет человека, работавшего с этой системой. Сандбокс сильно отличается по функционалу от продакшна.

Comment: Не) Я уже подробностей не помню. Самое яркое воспоминание - это поиск какого-нибудь живого аккаунта PayPal или карты банка нерезедента (так как наши тогда ещё непринимались), чтоб это все обкатать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делал я около года назад подписку, на stackoverflow есть мой [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409851/paypal-api-reccuring-payments), возможно вам чем то поможет.

IPN необходимо настроить в настройках аккаунта PayPal. Кстати sandbox от live отличается, но все же не сильно. Я отлаживал свою модуль в песочнице и при переходе на лайв проблем не было вообще.

В настройках IPN указываете URL своего сайта, на который будут отправляться ответы. Пример ответа можно посмотреть в IPN->History.

При получении IPN, необходимо сначала проверить валидность ответа и разобрать ответ.Далее уже по условиям.
Сразу после CreateRecurringProfile приходит ответ - `txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_created`. Означает что профиль создан. Если у вас был initial payment для старта подписки то второй ответ будет `txn_type=recurring_payment_completed` или что то вроде этого.

Платеж в песочнице долго идет, на лайве почти моментально. Подписку корректно разрулить можно только через IPN.

Сейчас кода обработчика нету под рукой, есть только класс который отправляет/принимает запросы. Если что - могу вечером посмотреть и скинуть как разбирать IPN`введите код здесь`

Comment: Кстати, пользователь Robert, который мне отвечал там, как я понял работает на PayPal, можете что не понятно у него попробовать спросить. Он всегда мне помогал, особенно когда некоторых вещей еще не было в документации, но ими уже можно было пользоваться :)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Теперь что-то прояснилось. Буду работать, о результатах доложу здесь.